# Export map as osm.pbf from QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, tile-server

I found a map on license CC-BY-3.0, added to QGIS and now I would like to export that in the way that allows me to run it on the tile server. I'll use tile server mentioned in this tutorial: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/using-a-docker-container/) I need it to be in the osm.pbf format.

Is that possible to use only QGIS to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of version 3.32 QGIS does not the capability to create OSM PBF files.